# Ambient light sensor support in GNOME 3.18

Tags: gnome, sensors

I have a Dell XPS 13 Laptop (old series) with ArchLinux and Gnome 3.18.
I've read in official [gnome 3.18 release notes](https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointSeventeen/ReleaseNotes#Ambient_light_sensor_support) that

> If a light sensor is present, GNOME will now automatically adjust the
>   display brightness in order to adjust for the ambient light level.
>
> Can be tested using a ColorHugALS device for those who don't have
>   built in hardware.
>
> Windows 8 compatible hardware is supported.
>
> A switch in the control center's power panel allows automatic display
>   brightness to be turned on/off.

<s>My ambient light sensor is not supported by Linux kernel out of the box, however I have compiled and installed / loaded [this module](https://github.com/victorenator/als) and now</s> my sensor appears as `/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0008:00/`. For example I can do

```
$ cat /sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0008:00/iio\:device0/in_illuminance_raw
153
```

and read current raw illuminance.

However this seems not to be detected / supported by gnome as I still don't get a "switch in the control center's power panel" and display brightness is not automatically adjusted.

[image]

How can I make it work?

Comment: @doc_crissti: yes in the mean time I had landed there too... I've installed it from AUR but still no luck. I issued a request here https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy/issues/46

Comment: Of course I will bit I'm still struggling...

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment and _lviggiani_'s patch answer is correct but the code has changed and this patch is no longer valid for the current git version.
A search and replace of `in_illuminance_input` to `in_illuminance_raw` in `src/drv-iio-poll-light.c` will also do the trick. I noticed however that om my Acer S7 the values of `_raw` are "on the low side" and i suspect that the kernel "corrects" them for known sensors when exposing them in `_input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I managed to get it working thanks to the support of one of the `iio-sensor-proxy` and kernel developers.

In my case I had to pull `iio-sensor-proxy` from [git](https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy) and apply this patch:

```
diff --git a/src/drv-iio-poll-light.c b/src/drv-iio-poll-light.c
index c2c5821..b568e78 100644
--- a/src/drv-iio-poll-light.c
+++ b/src/drv-iio-poll-light.c
@@ -37,7 +37,7 @@ iio_poll_light_discover (GUdevDevice *device)
        return FALSE;

    path = g_build_filename (g_udev_device_get_sysfs_path (device),
-                "in_illuminance_input",
+                "in_illuminance_raw",
                 NULL);
    ret = g_file_test (path, G_FILE_TEST_IS_REGULAR);
    g_free (path);
@@ -130,7 +130,7 @@ iio_poll_light_open (GUdevDevice        *device,

    drv_data->interval = get_interval (device);
    drv_data->input_path = g_build_filename (g_udev_device_get_sysfs_path (device),
-                        "in_illuminance_input",
+                        "in_illuminance_raw",
                         NULL);

    return TRUE;
```

Compiled and installed as per README instruction and finally enabled `iio-sensor-proxy.service`
Now I have automatic brightness adjustment working.

Finally, the dev has submitted a patch to linux kernel that in future will enable `iio-sensor-proxy` working out of the box also on computers having similar *ALS* without requiring to patch `iio-sensor-proxy`.

Comment: Which version of the Linux kernel will have this update? And without the kernel update, did the software itself have any update to address this?

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after I installed the "iio-sensor-proxy" package from the aur.

Comment: On dell xps 13?

Comment: On a Macbook Pro 13 2013 (but this should not matter). Gnome uses iio-sensor-proxy to access the sensors, so it is a requirement If you want to use those. I hope this helped.

Comment: This package worked on a Lenovo ThinkPad Helix as well to enable dbus events for the ambient light sensor.  Thank you!